# System.NullReferenceException when I test if NetworkStream is null

Tags: nullreferenceexception, networkstream

if I try to test this

```
if (mydeviceconnection.Devicestream != null)
```

I get System.NullReferenceException.
Visual studio says:

> mydeviceconnection.Devicestream was null.

Devicestream is a NetworkStream part of mydeviceconnection class.
I am trying this test to avoid NullReferenceException. This is already inside a try/catch so can run anyway but I was wondering if is possible to avoid the error.

Comment: Is it `mydeviceconnection.Devicestream` that's null, or `mydeviceconnection`?

Comment: Hi, it's Devicestream (according to VisualStudio). If I hover on mydeviceconnection in the code I don't get warnings and I can see all the elements of the class.

Comment: And it throws the exception on that if statement? Is the project building correctly?

Comment: Yes, app runs fine. Exception is in that statement. (Yellow highlight etc.)